# Is it legal to quote extracts from the GNU GPLv3 license on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, gpl

The GNU GPLv3 License is auto-licensed.

Content posted to the Stack Exchange network is licensed by CC BY-SA 3.0.

GNU is viral copyleft and cannot be re-licensed to CC, and also requires that *changing* of the license is *not allowed*.

**Is it legal to quote extracts from the GNU GPLv3 license (which is licensed by the GNU GPLv3 license) on the Stack Exchange network?**

Comment: Do you mean quoting extracts *from content* licensed under GPLv3?

Comment: @unor I mean a quote from the *actual* license, which *is* licensed under GPLv3

Comment: It becomes CC-BY-SA no more than a quote from a book or law code does. Wouldn't this fall under fair use?

Comment: @bithakr I'm not 100% clear on the definition of fair use, but it sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to the same extent that it is legal to quote extracts from any text without an explicit license to do so. If the usage of the excerpt qualifies as fair use, it can be done without a license.